# How to check if a state object is of type ICollection

Tags: c#, nhibernate, reflection, fluent-nhibernate, icollection

I use the nhibernate interceptor to compare values of the old state and the current state of the entity properties but some of the properties are of type `ICollection` so could anyone guide me about how to check if an object is of type `ICollection`

this is my code

```
    public void OnPostUpdate(NHibernate.Event.PostUpdateEvent @event)
    {
        var entityToAudit = @event.Entity as IAuditable;
        string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "AuditLog.txt");
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < @event.OldState.Length; i++)
            {
                string propertyName = @event.Persister.PropertyNames[i];
                if (@event.OldState[i] != null)
                {
                    if (!@event.OldState[i].Equals(@event.State[i]))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine("the value of "+ propertyName + " has been changed from " + @event.OldState[i] + " to " + @event.State[i]);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (@event.State[i] != null)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine("the value of "+ propertyName + " has been changed from being empty to " + @event.State[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Collections have their own kind of "previous"-state tracking anyway. There is (usually) only one instance of a collection, so you cannot compare it that easily. By the way, I wouldn't have a good feeling when writing to a file in an OnPostUpdate trigger. Apart from very bad performance, imagine the very nasty dead-locks you might get with circular file locks and database locks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have more than one options to do this, use **is** or use **as** with null checking:

```
if (obj is ICollection){
    //your logic
}
```

Or, if you need the object as ICollection later on, I recommend to use **as**:

```
var icoll = obj as ICollection
if (icoll != null){
    //use icoll
    //icoll.Something();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check the type using a simple **is**
like this:

```
var obj = getObject();
if(obj is TypeYouWant)
    doSomething();
```

Good Luck